# w3c validation congratulation ICON code results broken link

Tags: w3c, w3c-validation, broken-links

I have checked one of our sites (http://www.pantilimon.ro) in w3c validator, and took the congratulation icon HTML code, inserted into my code, but it contains two broken links: 
http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=referer
and
http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/check/referer

what to do now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They're not broken here. Could it be that you have some sort of firewall or proxy that removes the Referer request header?

Answer (score 0):

The links you have posted use the HTTP_REFERER header - that is, the URI of the page that you came from.

Use the actual URI.